# Visual Studio 2010 tab looks

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-interface, customization, visual-studio-extensions

Is there any extensions for Visual Studio 2010 to tweak the looks of the tab bar?
I miss the look of the tabs in Visual Studio 2005 with the slanted left edge and low height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tabs Studio](http://www.tabsstudio.com) extension (developed by me) with the Shaper add-in let you setup VS 2005 like tabs:
http://www.tabsstudio.com/documentation/style.html#CommunityStyles

Answer (score 0):

The only extension for tweaking the tab bar appearance in Visual Studio 2010 is the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/), but it doesn't let you bring back the angled appearance from Visual Studio 2005.